# Are there any better videos that the stanford iphone series?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Really enjoying the stanford iphone course videos, just wondering if there are others out there of equal or better quality?

Comment: I'm sure you could get them at a very high bitrate if you asked around...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I realize I am not answering the question directly, but what I found most helpful while I was getting into Cocoa development were:

- ADC videos
- [WWDC videos](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/) - These were even better than the Stanford courses because of the depth and emphasis on going beyond the assignment requirements.
- Jeff LaMarche's **Beginning iPhone Development** book (This came out later)
- Aaron Hillegass's Cocoa book (most helpful and motivating programming book I have ever read).

Comment: ADC stands for Apple Developer Connection (http://developer.apple.com/) I've highlighted the book name.

Answer (score 3):

check this: http://itunes.apple.com/itunes-u/advanced-iphone-development/id407243032

more advanced than the Stanford course

Answer (score 2):

You may also check peepcode screencast.

Answer (score 1):

I can highly recommend the [WWDC Videos](http://developer.apple.com/videos/). This year available for free.