# iphone development

Tags: iphone

I would like to build a music bisualiser for the iphone. I have development experience but not on the iphone platform. Can anyone recommend any books worth buying to get started...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer [Apple's Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html?section=Resource+Types&topic=Getting+Started) to begin with.There are a lot of forums and blogs to refer from once you have started development and want to refer on a particular topic.

You can use  ["Head First iPhone Development"](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596803551) as the first book to begin with programming in iPhone.

Cheers

Comment: Recommendations for learning resources [are off-topic for stackoverflow.com Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). However, this information [could be ok as part of a tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214338/997587).

Answer (score 0):

I started with this:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Beginning-iPhone-Games-Development-Professionals/dp/1430225998/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1296645855&sr=1-1-spell

and this:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Beginning-iPhone-Development-Exploring-SDK/dp/1430224592/ref=pd_bxgy_b_img_c

Answer (score 0):

For books and video for beginners, take a look at this post, pay attention to the 1st and 2nd highest voted answers, [Are there any better videos that the stanford iphone series?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586064/are-there-any-better-videos-that-the-stanford-iphone-series/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm an experienced (30+ years) architect/developer/etc. (C,C++,windows, linux, wxWidgets), but I had absolutely no Cocoa, Mac, Iphone, Objective-C etc. experience, and I got started on iPhone programming with:

> Beginning iPhone 3 Development:
>   Exploring the iPhone SDK by Dave Mark,
>   Jeff LaMarche

I really liked it.   I repeatedly referred to it while developing my first few apps, and before I knew enough to use the Apple documentation effictively.